# Mongodb - Add extra fields based on other field value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents in db in the following format:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5d6fb50852020c4a182fc773"),
"startTimestamp" : "1567601927157"
}
```

What I want to achieve is, using the "startTimestamp" value, create the following new fields:

- date (in the format "04-09-2019")
- hour (like "18")
- month (like "9")
- time (like "18:28:47")
- weekDay (like "Wednesday")

**Can I get a query to do the above operation in all the documents and finally create respective documents in the following format**:

```
{
"startTimestamp" : "1567601927157",
"date" : "04-09-2019",
"hour" : "18",
"month" : "9",
"time" : "18:28:47",
"weekDay" : "Wednesday",
}
```

**Edit:**
"startTimestamp" is not the only field present in the documents, it has other fields as well, like below:

```
 {
 "useCaseStatus" : "In Progress",
"feedbackRequested" : false,
"userFeedback" : null,
"startTimestamp" : "1567669352778"
 }
```

By adding new fields to the above document, **I dont want to delete the fields that are already present(because all the solutions I have got so far removes the other fields present in the documents)**. Also, adding one more expected document below (**Please note that hour and month fields are in string format, not int**):

```
{
 "useCaseStatus" : "In Progress",
"feedbackRequested" : false,
"userFeedback" : null,
"startTimestamp" : "1567669352778",
"endTimestamp" : null,
"date" : "05-09-2019",
"hour" : "13",
"month" : "9",
"time" : "13:12:32",
"weekDay" : "Thursday"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": { "date": { "$toDate": { "$toLong": "$startTimestamp" } } },
        "in": {
          "$mergeObjects": [
            {
              "date": { "$dateToString": { "date": "$$date", "format": "%d-%m-%Y" } },
              "month": { "$toString": { "$month": "$$date" } },
              "hour": { "$toString": { "$hour": "$$date" } },
              "time": { "$dateToString": { "date": "$$date", "format": "%H-%M-%S" } },
              "weekDay": { "$dayOfWeek": "$$date" }
            },
            "$$ROOT"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$out": "collectionName" }
])
```

[**Output**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IkqqU_LPLgJ)

```
{
  "date": "04-09-2019",
  "hour": 12,
  "month": 9,
  "startTimestamp": "1567601927157",
  "time": "12-58-47",
  "weekDay": 4
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for the answer. Your answer almost met the requirement. I missed to add few more details in the question, like "startTimestamp" is not the only field present in the documents. Your solution removes other fields present in the document other than "startTimestamp". Also, I would want 'hour' and 'month' field in string format. I have updated the question accordingly. Can you please check the same?

Comment: Updated my answer. Now it will provide you all other fields

Comment: Hi @Ashh, thanks again. Two things I noticed in your updated answer, one is that its not updating the real documents in the db, its just returning the updated documents. Second thing is that the 'hour', 'month' field in the query result is still in int format, can you please update your solution to update the document in db itself(not just returning the result) and to have the 'hour', 'month' field in string format?

Comment: Aggregation doesn't update the documents inside the db. It only returns the aggregated result. If it is a single time operation then use `$out` at the end of the pipeline.

Comment: Hi @Ashh, thanks again, I'm fairly new to mongodb, just starting to understand different operations supported by mongodb. And yes, this is a one time operation where I want to update the db. I would much appreciate if you could update your answer with the said "$out" operation at the end of the pipeline

Answer (score 1):

You need to start with [$toLong](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/index.html) and [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/index.html) to parse your string. Then you can use [$dateToParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToParts/index.html) and [$dayOfWeek](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfWeek/index.html). To translate number into string you can use [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/index.html)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            date: {
                $toDate: {
                    $toLong: "$startTimestamp"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            dateParts: { $dateToParts: { date: "$date" } },
            dayOfWeek: { $dayOfWeek: "$date" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            startTimestamp: 1,
            date: { $dateToString: { date: "$date", format: "%d-%m-%Y" } },
            hour: "$dateParts.hour",
            month: "$dateParts.month",
            time: { $dateToString: { date: "$date", format: "%H:%M:%S" } },
            weekDay: {
                $switch: {
                    branches: [
                        { case: { $eq: [ "$dayOfWeek", 1 ] }, then: "Sunday" },
                        { case: { $eq: [ "$dayOfWeek", 2 ] }, then: "Monday" },
                        { case: { $eq: [ "$dayOfWeek", 3 ] }, then: "Tuesday" },
                        { case: { $eq: [ "$dayOfWeek", 4 ] }, then: "Wednesday" },
                        { case: { $eq: [ "$dayOfWeek", 5 ] }, then: "Thursday" },
                        { case: { $eq: [ "$dayOfWeek", 6 ] }, then: "Friday" }
                    ],
                    default: "Saturday"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2Pc2aafFANR)

Comment: thanks so much for the answer. Your answer almost met the requirement. I missed to add few more details in the question, like "startTimestamp" is not the only field present in the documents. I have updated the question accordingly. Can you please check the same?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement aggregate pipeline and use date operators available but as you have millisecond saved in string first we have to convert it to int then date then perfrom date operators notice some of them will need timezone to give accurate result instead will just give utc results

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      longMillis: {
        $toLong: "$startTimestamp"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      startTimestamp: 1,
      "date": {
        "$add": [
          new Date(0),
          "$longMillis"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      startTimestamp: 1,
      month: {
        $month: "$date"
      },
      day: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: {
                $eq: [
                  {
                    $dayOfMonth: "$date"
                  },
                  1
                ]
              },
              then: "Sunday"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $eq: [
                  {
                    $dayOfMonth: "$date"
                  },
                  2
                ]
              },
              then: "Monday"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $eq: [
                  {
                    $dayOfMonth: "$date"
                  },
                  3
                ]
              },
              then: "Tuesday"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $eq: [
                  {
                    $dayOfMonth: "$date"
                  },
                  4
                ]
              },
              then: "Wednesday"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $eq: [
                  {
                    $dayOfMonth: "$date"
                  },
                  5
                ]
              },
              then: "Thursday"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $eq: [
                  {
                    $dayOfMonth: "$date"
                  },
                  6
                ]
              },
              then: "Friday"
            },
            {
              case: {
                $eq: [
                  {
                    $dayOfMonth: "$date"
                  },
                  7
                ]
              },
              then: "Saturday"
            },

          ],
          default: 6
        }
      },
      hour: {
        $hour: {
          "date": "$date",
          "timezone": "+05:30"
        }
      },
      date: {
        $dateToString: {
          format: "%d-%m-%Y",
          date: "$date"
        }
      },
      time: {
        $dateToString: {
          format: "%H:%M:%S",
          date: "$date",
          timezone: "+05:30"
        }
      },

    }
  }
])
```

Giving result:

```
[
  {
    "date": "04-09-2019",
    "day": "Wednesday",
    "hour": 18,
    "month": 9,
    "startTimestamp": "1567601927157",
    "time": "18:28:47"
  }
]
```